# A List that automatically re-sizes when an element is inserted at an index greater than current List size

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

How can I create a `List<T>` that re-sizes, if an element is added at an index greater than current list size without throwing any RuntimeException. Consider the following code sample:

```
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Assuming current list size is 10, Let's insert at a very large index.
    int index = 10000;
    myList.add(index, "test");
```

The add operation would result in IndexOutOfBoundException if the index exceeds list size.

I expect the list to be sparsely populated so its size should be proportional to number of non null values.

Comment: using `index` and growable collection isn't present in `java`, either don't use `index` while adding or write your custom logic over existing collection ie `ArrayList`

Comment: How about a map then?

Comment: Each index represents the EditDistance between two strings. For example edit distance between book --> test = 4 so the index at 4 would have test. I am actually implementing a variant of BK trees. I am looking for a collection with comparatively lesser memory overhead because as the tree grows the child nodes will have children list of very less size.

Comment: each index represents the edit distance between two strings? Then you will have one list for 'book', one list for 'magazine', etc?

Comment: @Anupam: What is wrong with a `Map<Integer, String>`? It covers exactly the functionality you are asking for.

Comment: @jarnbjo: There is nothing wrong with Map<Integer, String>. In fact I am currently using a Hashmap. I am specifically looking for a library that does the list resize.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to implement a sparse list in java is simply to use a hash map

```
Map<Integer, String> sparseList = new HashMap<>();
```

To add an element to a list:

```
sparseList.put(index, value)
```

To remove an element:

```
sparseList.remove(index);
```

To query an element:

```
sparseList.get(index); // Will return null if no element at this position
```

If you need to tell the difference between null and not set you can do

```
sparseList.containsKey(index);
```

In this case the list will not retain the order of elements, if that is important you can swap the HashMap for a TreeMap.

Comment: TreeMap will maintain ordering.

Comment: Very true, I'll add that.